# MongoDb authentication using Hibernate OGM

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

I'm able to authenticate on my mongodb using the shell command:

```
#mongo -u user -p pwd --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show users
{
        "_id" : "admin.ladmin",
        "user" : "ladmin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "admin.living",
        "user" : "user",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "lvdb"
                }
        ]
}
```

I've also been able to authenticate on it using java driver:

```
List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
seeds.add(new ServerAddress(this.configurationResources.getMongodbServer(), this.configurationResources.getMongodbPort()));

List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
credentials.add(
    MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(
        this.configurationResources.getMongodbUsername(),
        this.configurationResources.getMongodbAuthenticationDatabase(),
        this.configurationResources.getMongodbPassword().toCharArray()
    )
);

this.mongoClient = new MongoClient(seeds, credentials);
```

Currently, I'm engaged on a project I want to use Hibernate OGM. I've set `persistence.xml` file:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="mongo" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

        <class>com.living.persistence.entities.User</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="lvdb"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="mongo"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port" value="27017"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username" value="user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password" value="pwd"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.authentication_mechanism" value="SCRAM_SHA_1"/>

            <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.connection_timeout" value="5000"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.document.association_storage" value="IN_ENTITY"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.association_document_storage" value="GLOBAL_COLLECTION"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.write_concern" value="MAJORITY"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.read_preference" value="PRIMARY_PREFERRED"></property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

As you can see I'm using `SCRAM-SHA1` as authentication mechanism.

Nevertheless, I'm getting this message when I'm trying to deploy my application:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: OGM000071: Unable to start datatore provider
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: OGM001214: Unable to connect to MongoDB instance: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongo:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='lvdb', password=, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server mongo:27017. The full response is { \"ok\" : 0.0, \"errmsg\" : \"Authentication failed.\", \"code\" : 18, \"codeName\" : \"AuthenticationFailed\" }}}]
>       Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongo:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='lvdb', password=, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server mongo:27017. The full response is { \"ok\" : 0.0, \"errmsg\" : \"Authentication failed.\", \"code\" : 18, \"codeName\" : \"AuthenticationFailed\" }}}]"}}

Comment: This problem is now fixed on master and the next release should work

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate OGM is currently using the database name as authentication database. This is a bug, I'm working on it right now.

In your example (all seems correct by the way), you want to connect to the
"lvdb" db but you defined the user in the "admin" database. Hiebernate OGM is actually looking for the user in the "lvdb" database.

**UPDATE**: This problem has now been fixed in the latest stable release (5.1.0.Final), you can use the property `hibernate.ogm.mongodb.authentication_database` to select the name of the authentication database (`admin` is the default name).